# File upload after dropdown selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Dropdown list & file uploader.Here i need, when dropdown list selected & after that need to load the file uploader.In my coding always it shows there's no File.
Here i need SelectedValue passes to the database with file uploader.

My Code

```
 protected void drpuser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guid SelectedUserId =Guid.Parse(drpuser.SelectedValue);
    FileUploader();
}
```

FileUploader

```
 public void FileUploader()
{

   // var user = Membership.GetUser();
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
    {

        Guid SelectedUserId = Guid.Parse(drpuser.SelectedValue); //<-- value correct

        foreach (string s in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileExtension = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            Guid UserGUID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

            string UserFolderPath = "~/UploadedFiles/" + UserGUID;
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(UserFolderPath));

            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(UserFolderPath), fileName);
            string FullPath = UserFolderPath + "/" + fileName;
            file.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

            da.AddAdminFiles(UserGUID, FullPath, DateTime.Now, true, SelectedUserId);
        }
    }
else
{

}
```

Comment: If you select the file, then *OnSelectedIndexChanged* event, Request.Files.Count should be 1. Can you please check this property before foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the file will only be posted on actual submit.. Im not sure if an AutoPostBack will automatically submit file over and over.. probably too much HTTP Overhead.

If you can, add a "submit" button instead, and have the user choose an item from the drop down list and supply a file.  Then when user submits, look for the HTTP file, and it should be in the Request Object.